# JNI: What type of CallStaticMethod to use?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

**EDITED**
I'm calling a java method from C. Previous attempt with simple datatypes like int the code is working fine until i decided to use the actual **java.util.Map** as the return value of the java method.

```
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "doProcess", "()Ljava/util/Map;");
```

Now when i try to use the following statements to get the return value

```
jobject returnedValue = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazz, mid);
```

I'm not even sure if CallStatic**Object**Method and **jobject** is the correct types to use.

I declared the map as `Map<String, String>` and expecting to get two string value (key,value) for every pair.

How can i possibly get the map value from 'jobject' type? I can probably become successful when i iterate through the map and return strings in the loop. But i'm looking for a solid solution where i can return the map instead as a collection and assign in to my C++ map structure or alike.
I need the values of every key-value pair

Comment: Well, what is the Java signature of the method? What signature is printed by `javap -s`? Why should a `jobect` have a `size()` member?

Comment: Read the post its "()Ljava/util/Map;" was printed by javap -s
I'm assuming that jobject should have size since it's representing a map structure. Since it doesn't work, I'm asking anyone who can answer the question above. BTW, what's with the down vote?

Comment: I read the post. There is nothing it about having used `javap -s`, and there is nothing there about the Java signature of the method either, which is what I asked for. Nor in your comment. The Java signature isn't the same thing as the JNI signature.

Comment: To the fact that i used "()Ljava/util/Map;" why would you still ask what was printed by javap -s? You don't believe that "()Ljava/util/Map;" is the printed signature of javap -s? the return value of the java function is of type Map<String,String> which has the correct signature i mentioned. Anyway, i'm not asking about what correct signature to use. I'm asking help on how to get the returned map value from the java method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight-forward, it's just a lot of steps to go through.

Let's say I have this method in my Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    public static Map<String, String> getTheMap() {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("FooKey", "FooVal");
        map.put("BarKey", "BarVal");
        return map;
    }

    ...

    public native void convertMap();
}
```

Then I could do this in my C++ code:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_ndkbuildtest_MainActivity_convertMap(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    // Obtain the Map instance and its class
    jclass main_activity_class = env->GetObjectClass(thiz);
    jmethodID get_the_map = env->GetStaticMethodID(main_activity_class, "getTheMap", "()Ljava/util/Map;");
    jobject java_map = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(main_activity_class, get_the_map);
    jclass map_class = env->GetObjectClass(java_map);

    // Obtain the key set and its class
    jclass set_class = env->FindClass("java/util/Set");
    jmethodID get_key_set = env->GetMethodID(map_class, "keySet", "()Ljava/util/Set;");
    jmethodID get_value = env->GetMethodID(map_class, "get", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jobject java_key_set = env->CallObjectMethod(java_map, get_key_set);

    // Convert the key set to an array that we can iterate over easily
    jmethodID set_toarray = env->GetMethodID(set_class, "toArray", "()[Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jobjectArray java_key_array = static_cast<jobjectArray>(env->CallObjectMethod(java_key_set, set_toarray));
    jint len = env->GetArrayLength(java_key_array);

    // Insert all the key,value pairs into a std::map
    std::map<std::string, std::string> native_map;
    for (jint i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        jstring java_key = static_cast<jstring>(env->GetObjectArrayElement(java_key_array, i));
        jstring java_value = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(java_map, get_value, java_key));
        const char *key_chars = env->GetStringUTFChars(java_key, NULL);
        const char *value_chars = env->GetStringUTFChars(java_value, NULL);
        native_map.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key_chars, value_chars));
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(java_key, key_chars);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(java_value, value_chars);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(java_key);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(java_value);
    }

    // Print the result
    for (const auto& kv : native_map) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "convertMap", "nativeMap contains <%s, %s>", kv.first.c_str(), kv.second.c_str());
    }
}
```

I've left out any error handling. In production code you obviously shouldn't do that.

Comment: I like this approach i'll choose this as the answer. However, i'm a little bit worried if this approach is expensive because there's too much method to find a class. I'm thinking of returning the strings in an array instead. What do you think?

Comment: If you're worried about class/method lookup taking too much time (I suggest you measure this first), you could do those in your `JNI_OnLoad` function and cache the results (for the `jclass`es you need to use `NewGlobalRef` to make sure that they will be valid for future use).

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class JNIDemo {
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("JNIDemo");
        }
        public static Map<String,String> getMap(){
            Map<String,String> demo = new HashMap<String,String>();
            demo.put("M","p");
            return demo;

        }

        public native static void useMap();
    }

JNIDemo.h

    /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
    #include <jni.h>
    /* Header for class JNIDemo */

    #ifndef _Included_JNIDemo
    #define _Included_JNIDemo
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
    /*
     * Class:     JNIDemo
     * Method:    useMap
     * Signature: ()V
     */
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIDemo_useMap
      (JNIEnv *, jclass);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
    #endif

JNIDemo.c

    #include <jni.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "JNIDemo.h"

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIDemo_useMap(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls){
      jmethodID getMap = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "getMap", "()Ljava/util/Map;");
      jobject jParameterMap =  (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env,cls, getMap);
      jclass c_Map = (*env)-> FindClass(env,"java/util/Map");
      jmethodID m_GetSize = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, c_Map, "size", "()I");
       int jSize = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, jParameterMap, m_GetSize);
          printf("Size = %i\n", jSize );

       return;
    }
```

Comment: I already know this example. My question is how can i get the value from jParameterMap?  I need the key value pairs not the size of the map.

Comment: Hi Follow something like this:                                                           
     jmethodID entrySet = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, c_Map, "entrySet", "()Ljava/util/Map$Entry");
  jobject m_entrySet = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jParameterMap, entrySet);

Comment: Then iterate on it:                                                                                                         jclass set= (*env)->FindClass(env,"java/util/Set");
    jmethodID iteratorID =  (*env)->GetMethodID(env,set, "iterator", "()Ljava/util/Iterator;");
    jclass iterator =  (*env)->FindClass(env,"java/util/Iterator");
    jmethodID hasNextID =  (*env)->GetMethodID(env,iterator, "hasNext", "()Z");
    jmethodID nextID =  (*env)->GetMethodID(env,iterator, "next", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");